# How to continuously read data from different html page into one curly bracket in JSON file using PHP?

Tags: php, html, json

I managed to extract data from `JSON` file using `PHP`. im new in `PHP` and `JSON`. i made some pages of html form and i want that data of the same person that sign in be kept in same curly brackets in `JSON` file. Also, i don't have a 'parent' and 'child' type of `JSON` file as in member id as parent and name, age, gender etc as child.

For example, this is what I have in my `JSON` file (which is `member.json`) from two pages of html form (which is register and select ticket page) by the same person:

```
{
   "name": "iron man",
   "age": "54",
   "gender": "male",
   "email": "i@r.m",
   "username": "ironman",
   "Password": "ironman",
   "submit": "Submit"
}{
   "Journey_From": "Segambut",
   "Journey_To": "Kepong",
   "date": "2018-09-12",
   "time": "15:43",
   "Quantity": "3",
   "submit": "Proceed"
}
```

I don't know how to put two inputs from different html form of the same person into one {}

I want it to be like this:

```
{
   "name": "iron man",
   "age": "54",
   "gender": "male",
   "email": "i@r.m",
   "username": "ironman",
   "Password": "ironman",
   "submit": "Submit"
   "Journey_From": "Segambut",
   "Journey_To": "Kepong",
   "date": "2018-09-12",
   "time": "15:43",
   "Quantity": "3",
   "submit": "Proceed"
}
```

I used this code in both html page to send the input of the page to `member.json` file.

```
 <?php
   if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
      $file = "member.json";
      $json_string = json_encode($_POST, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
      file_put_contents($file, $json_string, FILE_APPEND); 
   }
 ?>
```

After using the 'die' code:

```
  array(7) { ["name"]=> string(4) "haha" ["age"]=> string(2) "34" ["gender"]=> string(4) "male" ["email"]=> string(5) "d@w.f" ["username"]=> string(4) "haha" ["Password"]=> string(4) "haha" ["submit"]=> string(6) "Submit" }
```

Comment: The problem with append mode is that it can't write before your ending `}`. The other problem is your file isn't valid json once it encounters `}{`. I'd approach this by reading the file into memory, and rebuilding the file. If it's gonna be valid json, you should have an array containing all the posts like this:
`[{.....},{.....}]` etc

Comment: could you type `die(var_dump($_POST));` right after if statement and see what it shows.

Comment: @Ultimater can you suggest some reference pages that i can look into to do what you hv suggested?

Comment: @MarkoMackic it shows that i now have 7 arrays that shows name as array1, age as array2 and so on rather than 1 array with 7 elements in it.

Comment: Please paste the output you see in edited question

Comment: [`array_merge`](http://php.net/array_merge) ( [`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode)  + [`$_POST`](http://php.net/_POST) ) → [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode)  [`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/file_put_contents). Though the data looks like a database might be better fit than file mangling.

Comment: What I'm suggesting is: file_get_contents and json_decode for reading file into PHP array. Then decide if you want to use array_push to add your new data, or array_merge to merge it with a previous post. When you're ready to write, use json_encode followed by file_put_contents. Check php.net on these functions to see how to use them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `arary_merge()` function to get that done.
Check the `json` file before putting any content there. If there is any content available there you can just fetch those `json_data` as array and merge them with the current one. Then push the new merged array to the json file.
You can check my demo code about what i'm talking about.

**append.php**

```
<?php
function append($file, $new_json) {
    $file_content = file_get_contents($file);
    $previous_json = json_decode($file_content, true);

    $previous_json == null ? $previous_json = [] : $previous_json = $previous_json; 
    $new_data = array_merge($previous_json, $new_json);

    $json_string = json_encode($new_data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    file_put_contents($file, $json_string); 
}
```

Then in any of your page from where you are inserting data you just `require` the `append.php` file like this

```
<?php 
    include_once 'append.php';
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $file = "member.json";
        $newData = $_POST;
        append($file, $newData);
    }
?>
```

Note: You can use `submit1` and `submit2` to get both **submit** values.
Please check this to know more about `array_merge` http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Comment: this worked perfectly. thank you so much! but it doesnt add up information of another member into the member.json file. how to make sure that file hold other member's record as well? currently the file replaces the old member's info with a new member's one and the old record is gone.